# How to export/import MS Office Communicator contacts?

Tags: ms-office, office-communicator

I had MOC 2005 re-installed on my office PC recently, and found to my chagrine that it had lost all of my contacts. I've searched for ways to export/import the contacts list, but have not found any useful answers. Some suggest looking in the registry at key tree `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Communicator`, but all I find are the titles of the contact groups I used to have (as binary Unicode values), but which MOC no longer recognizes.

My plan is to export the registry (or data file) values and then write a script to re-instate them, I just need to know where to find those values.

Any suggestions?

**Update**

I think I may have found the answer myself. I located an XML file in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\
  Microsoft\Communicator\presence_User_Name_Company_Com.xml
```

which appears to contain all my contact info.

I plan to examine it a little further soon.

Answer (score 2):

open this file in excel from the following location C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\ 
  Microsoft\Communicator\presence_User_Name_Company_Com.xml . all the contacts will be arranged in a single column. you can save it....:) easy way to take a bakup....

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I found (see above).

Comment: I found this worked for me instead.
-Open %USERPROFILE%\TRACING on the client
-Locate the most recent Communicator-uccapi-0.uccapilog log file
See (http://blogs.technet.com/b/markbarr/archive/2010/04/21/how-to-export-your-communicator-2007-contacts.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to export directly the contents of the whole OCS map. But you can manually proceed to a separate export.
Select the content of each group you have in your OCS, cut and paste in a notepad window.
You get there a liste of mail addresses separated by semicolumns.
create the complete list step by step, group by group.
Once the list is created, you can send it to your friends, and they just have to create the groups in their own OCS, and group by group, cut and paste the rows of addresses in the group. 
The group is automatically updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Office Communicator client for Mac, you can save your contacts list and then import them. The only thing it doesn't do is retain the groups, if you have organized contact groups.

Answer (score 1):

For MS Communicator 2005 running on Windows 7, you can find the file here:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\presence_User_Name_Company_Com.xml

We don't have Communicator 2010 at our site, perhaps some could confirm if this path/file is correct for more recent versions.